# three.js: BufferGeometry with texture coordinates

Tags: three.js

I could not found example of THREE.BufferGeometry with texture coordinates. Is it supposed to be used for textured mesh? I can't get it to work. Here is my test code:

```js
var quad_vertices =
[
    -30.0,  30.0, 0.0,
     30.0,  30.0, 0.0,
     30.0, -30.0, 0.0,
    -30.0, -30.0, 0.0
];

var quad_uvs =
[
    0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 1.0
];

var quad_indices =
[
    0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2
];

var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

geometry.attributes =
{
    position:
    {
        itemSize: 3,
        array: new Float32Array(3 * 4)
    },

    uv:
    {
        itemSize: 2,
        array: new Float32Array(2 * 4)
    },

    index:
    {
        itemSize: 1,
        array: new Uint16Array(6)
    }
};

var positions = geometry.attributes.position.array;
var uvs       = geometry.attributes.uv.array;
var indices   = geometry.attributes.index.array;

var i;
for(i = 0; i < positions.length; i += 3)
{
    positions[i]     = quad_vertices[i];
    positions[i + 1] = quad_vertices[i + 1];
    positions[i + 2] = quad_vertices[i + 2];
}

for(i = 0; i < uvs.length; i += 2)
{
    uvs[i]     = quad_uvs[i];
    uvs[i + 1] = quad_uvs[i + 1];
}

for(i = 0; i < indices.length; i++)
    indices[i] = quad_indices[i];

var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./assets/texture.png');
texture.anisotropy = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

mesh.position.z = -100;

scene.add(mesh);
```

Just creating mesh with THREE.Geometry is OK so I have no idea what can be wrong with this code. Any thoughts?

Comment: Look at `THREE.BufferGeometryUtils.fromGeometry( geometry, settings )`. Also, quads are no longer supported by three.js. Update to r.61.

Comment: I don't have to create BufferGeometry from Geometry, right?  So that would be nothing more than a workaround. Also I am not using three.js quads.

Comment: You do not, but if you used that function once, you would at least see how the `BufferGeometry` was created.

Comment: Can't see what is wrong with my code even after reading BufferGeometryUtils.js Seems like there are no indexes created but does that matter? They are created in http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry and everything is OK. But not with my code. Nothing is rendered at all, not even some corrupted geometry.

Comment: I think you may need to create an offset for the geometry. See my question & answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613281/three-js-mesh-based-on-buffergeometry-not-appearing

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I think maybe you need to set the vertices explicitly without using 'index', since that's how it's done in the function that WestLangley mentioned. However, I spent some time looking at the (minimal) documentation on the format here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Geometry-format-4 and noticed that the faces seem to be defined as a series of indices into the attribute arrays, starting with flags for the face that tell three.js what the face format is, so presumably it's possible to use indices, although I can't get it to work with uvs :(

Comment: Had a similar problem with indexes when i made my own custom BufferGeometry, I just left indexes out of my create code and it all worked fine

Answer (score 11):

Here is a working example of indexed BufferGeometry with uvs. I updated your example to work with three.js r83. I saw two problems with the old code. First, you can't just set geometry.attributes equal to a JSON object definition. THREE.BufferAttribute is a class, but your JSON is missing the function definitions on its prototype that are required by the THREE.Renderer. Second THREE.ImageUtils has been replaced by THREE.TextureLoader, so I updated that in the example as well.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var quad_vertices = [
  -30.0, 30.0, 0.0,
  30.0, 30.0, 0.0,
  30.0, -30.0, 0.0, 
  -30.0, -30.0, 0.0
];

var quad_uvs = [
  0.0, 0.0,
  1.0, 0.0,
  1.0, 1.0,
  0.0, 1.0
];

var quad_indices = [
  0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2
];

var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

var vertices = new Float32Array(quad_vertices);
// Each vertex has one uv coordinate for texture mapping
var uvs = new Float32Array(quad_uvs);
// Use the four vertices to draw the two triangles that make up the square.
var indices = new Uint32Array(quad_indices)

// itemSize = 3 because there are 3 values (components) per vertex
geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
geometry.setAttribute('uv', new THREE.BufferAttribute(uvs, 2));
geometry.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(indices, 1));

// Load the texture asynchronously
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
textureLoader.load('http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/textures/crate.gif', function(texture) {
  console.log('texture loaded');

  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: texture
  });
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  mesh.position.z = -100;

  scene.add(mesh);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}, undefined, function(err) {
  console.error('texture not loaded', err)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

For further reference:

[Creating a scene](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/Creating-a-scene)

[BufferAttribute](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferAttribute)

Answer (score 3):

For those looking to combine an indexed buffer geometry with a texture and a custom shader material (I believe this approaches the upper bound of performance), I used the following approach. All of the real work happens in `loadImage()` and in the vertex and fragment shaders, the rest is just boilerplate to set up Three.js (version 92):

```js
/**
* Generate a scene object with a background color
**/

function getScene() {
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
  return scene;
}

/**
* Generate the camera to be used in the scene. Camera args:
*   [0] field of view: identifies the portion of the scene
*     visible at any time (in degrees)
*   [1] aspect ratio: identifies the aspect ratio of the
*     scene in width/height
*   [2] near clipping plane: objects closer than the near
*     clipping plane are culled from the scene
*   [3] far clipping plane: objects farther than the far
*     clipping plane are culled from the scene
**/

function getCamera() {
  var aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspectRatio, 0.1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(0, 1, 10);
  return camera;
}

/**
* Generate the renderer to be used in the scene
**/

function getRenderer() {
  // Create the canvas with a renderer
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
  // Add support for retina displays
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  // Specify the size of the canvas
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  // Add the canvas to the DOM
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  return renderer;
}

/**
* Generate the controls to be used in the scene
* @param {obj} camera: the three.js camera for the scene
* @param {obj} renderer: the three.js renderer for the scene
**/

function getControls(camera, renderer) {
  var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.zoomSpeed = 0.4;
  controls.panSpeed = 0.4;
  return controls;
}

/**
* Load image
**/

function loadImage() {

  var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

  /*
  Now we need to push some vertices into that geometry to identify the coordinates the geometry should cover
  */

  // Identify the image size
  var imageSize = {width: 10, height: 7.5};

  // Identify the x, y, z coords where the image should be placed
  var coords = {x: -5, y: -3.75, z: 0};

  // Add one vertex for each corner of the image, using the 
  // following order: lower left, lower right, upper right, upper left
  var vertices = new Float32Array([
    coords.x, coords.y, coords.z, // bottom left
    coords.x+imageSize.width, coords.y, coords.z, // bottom right
    coords.x+imageSize.width, coords.y+imageSize.height, coords.z, // upper right
    coords.x, coords.y+imageSize.height, coords.z, // upper left
  ])

  // set the uvs for this box; these identify the following corners:
  // lower-left, lower-right, upper-right, upper-left
  var uvs = new Float32Array([
    0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
  ])

  // indices = sequence of index positions in `vertices` to use as vertices
  // we make two triangles but only use 4 distinct vertices in the object
  // the second argument to THREE.BufferAttribute is the number of elements
  // in the first argument per vertex
  geometry.setIndex([0,1,2, 2,3,0])
  geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ));
  geometry.addAttribute('uv', new THREE.BufferAttribute( uvs, 2) )

  // Create a texture loader so we can load our image file
  var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

  // specify the url to the texture
  var url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/duhaime/blog/tsne-webgl/assets/cat.jpg';

  // specify custom uniforms and attributes for shaders
  // Uniform types: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Uniforms-types
  var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({  
    uniforms: {
      texture: {
        type: 't',
        value: loader.load(url)
      },
    },
    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertex-shader').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragment-shader').textContent
  });

  // Combine our image geometry and material into a mesh
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  // Set the position of the image mesh in the x,y,z dimensions
  mesh.position.set(0,0,0)

  // Add the image to the scene
  scene.add(mesh);
}

/**
* Render!
**/

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  controls.update();
};

var scene = getScene();
var camera = getCamera();
var renderer = getRenderer();
var controls = getControls(camera, renderer);
loadImage();

render();
```

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000; }
body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/92/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
<script type='x-shader/x-vertex' id='vertex-shader'>
  /**
  * The vertex shader's main() function must define `gl_Position`,
  * which describes the position of each vertex in the space.
  *
  * To do so, we can use the following variables defined by Three.js:        
  *   
  *   uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix - combines:
  *     model matrix: maps a point's local coordinate space into world space
  *     view matrix: maps world space into camera space
  *
  *   uniform mat4 projectionMatrix - maps camera space into screen space
  *
  *   attribute vec3 position - sets the position of each vertex
  *
  *   attribute vec2 uv - determines the relationship between vertices and textures
  *
  * `uniforms` are constant across all vertices
  *
  * `attributes` can vary from vertex to vertex and are defined as arrays
  * with length equal to the number of vertices. Each index in the array
  * is an attribute for the corresponding vertex
  *
  * `varyings` are values passed from the vertex to the fragment shader
  **/

  varying vec2 vUv; // pass the uv coordinates of each pixel to the frag shader

  void main() {
    vUv = uv;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
  }
</script>

<script type='x-shader/x-fragment' id='fragment-shader'>
  /**
  * The fragment shader's main() function must define `gl_FragColor`,
  * which describes the pixel color of each pixel on the screen.
  *
  * To do so, we can use uniforms passed into the shader and varyings
  * passed from the vertex shader
  **/

  precision highp float; // set float precision (optional)

  uniform sampler2D texture; // identify the texture as a uniform argument
  varying vec2 vUv; // identify the uv values as a varying attribute

  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, vUv);
  }
</script>
```