# Can I apply a normal map across an entire merged buffered geometry?

Tags: three.js

I'm merging PlaneBufferGeometry's to make a larger plane constructed of squares. After merging the geometries I can apply a material that gets added to each individual geometry in the mesh.

Is it possible to apply a material to the entire merged geometry? I want to have a normal map that goes across the entire plane instead of repeated on each square.

https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merging geometries in this way also merges the texture coordinates of each plane geometry. If you don't want this behavior, you have to discard the final `uv` buffer attribute and generate a new one. Assuming your final plane geometry lies in the `xy` plane, you can use the minimum and maximum `xy` values to generate texture coordinate in the range [0,1] for all vertices.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. By setting the index and position/uv attributes I was able to get the texture and normal map to cover the entire merged geometry. (reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504337/three-js-buffergeometry-with-texture-coordinates)


I was hoping to have the texture tiled though with the normal map spread across the entire geometry. I think what I'll do is create a tiled texture from the original image and stretch that across the merged geometry.


Unless it's possible to use two materials, one with the tiled texture and one with the stretched uv map?

Comment: The diffuse and normal map always share the same sets of uv coordinates. I don't think using two materials will work since you need the diffuse and normal map in the same shader program.